# Putting assets and public under another folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm writing a website that assigns URLs under the root domain to various user-specified records, so I'm trying to leave as many top-level paths unused as possible. Thus, I'd like to put everything in `public`, including `assets`, under a subfolder (e.g. `404.html` would become `edit/404.html`, `assets/users.css` would become `edit/assets/users.css`, etc.). Is there a simple and sane way to do this that'll keep things like `image_tag` working?